# Notification to show on the same screen as the application

Tags: java, swing, notifications, awt, java-11

I am using ch.swingfx.twinkle NotificationBuilder in my application.

```
NotificationBuilder builder = new NotificationBuilder().withMessage(message).withTitle(title).withStyle(notificationStyle).withFadeInAnimation(true).withFadeOutAnimation(true);

builder.showNotification()
```

I want the notification to appear on the monitor screen my application is present. How to achieve the same ?

I tried using withPosition but it did not work.

```
NotificationBuilder builder = new NotificationBuilder().withMessage(message).withTitle(title).withStyle(notificationStyle).withFadeInAnimation(true).withFadeOutAnimation(true).withPosition(
            new ch.swingfx.twinkle.window.IPosition() {
                @Override
                public java.awt.Point getPosition(java.awt.Dimension dimension, java.awt.Insets insets,
                                                  javax.swing.JWindow jWindow,
                                                  ch.swingfx.twinkle.style.INotificationStyle iNotificationStyle) {
                    JWindow window = new javax.swing.JWindow(this.getGraphicsConfiguration());
                    int x = dimension.width / 2 - window.getWidth() / 2;
                    int y = dimension.height / 2 - window.getHeight() / 2 - iNotificationStyle.getWindowInsets().bottom / 2 + iNotificationStyle.getWindowInsets().top / 2;
                    return new Point(x, y);
                }
            });
```